# Should controllers in Spring MVC app always work only with detached objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, dao

It is a good practice to work in controller and view of Spring MVC application with JPA detached objects?

If yes, then only gain of lazy initialization is in scope of single DAO call - am I right?
Also, with lot of operations don't spreaded in multiple controllers (beacause all data-action must be executed in single dao-transactional-call) how to split DAO operations to more classes? Create specialized, related only by entity DAOs?

Is it possible to span a transaction on controller method call, not single DAO call? And would it be a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions should be on your service layer classes, and sometimes on your daos/repositories. But definitely not on your controllers.

You have two dao calls, and you want one transaction ? That is exactly what a service class is for.

Comment: So I assume: service class with 2 injected DAOs, called from controller. Little last questions: How to annotate service? It is injected like DAOs to controller?

Comment: Yes, and use @Service annotation on the service class, and it can then be autowired etc.

Comment: Also, many people (not me) say you should never inject a dao directly into a controller, they should always be accessed via a service. And that transactions only go one serivces not dao's (but its debatable).

Comment: What if I have complicated service method to retreive results (where I already have to decide between lazy/full init), but use it in mutiple context: full-data required and only-basic-data-required (lazy) - I'm stuck with detached object and also I should not clone service logic only to add join/some initialisation/fetch-type-setting (Don't Repeat Yourself).